# How does the JVM determine where FileDescriptor.out (STDOUT) goes on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, jvm, sas

I have an issue hovering somewhere between the JVM and Windows, and I fear I'm not knowledgeable enough about either to ask the question very well, but here goes:

I have some non-Java code (it's SAS SCL code, but I'm hoping that a knowledge of SAS isn't necessary to answer this) that launches a Java process and redirects its STDOUT and STDERR streams to SAS's conception of a named pipe. That Java process writes some text to System.out. The SAS code then attempts to read that text from the pipe.

This has worked for a long time on many systems, but recently problems have cropped up on Windows. The issues <strike>*might* be specific to Java 7 (though possibly Java 6 as well)</strike>, and/or *possibly* specific to Windows 7 and later.

There are two contexts from which this code may be called. In one context, it works fine; in the other, SAS doesn't see any output from the Java process (which appears to be running successfully based on other output). When it doesn't work, the 'fread' call appears to block until the Java process is complete; however, that call just returns 'EOF'.

(Specifically: if run from a SAS Workspace Server process, it works. If it runs from batch-mode SAS, it doesn't. I'm not clear what exactly is different between these two environments, though the process owner is different.)

In the case where it doesn't work, I briefly see a Windows console window that contains the STDOUT output that SAS should be but isn't seeing. In the case where it does work, I don't see such a window, but that might be a result of the process running under a different OS user than the one I'm logged in as.

Given all that, I guess my question is: how does the JVM determine where STDOUT ends up? Could the JVM be writing the output to a console window instead of the desired STDOUT stream connected to the SAS pipe? What are the salient aspects of the environment that the JVM looks at when making this determination?

**EDIT 2013-02-20:**

Further investigation shows that when launching the Java process, SAS does the following:

```
cmd /C <java command>
```

This is done in both contexts in which the code is run.

I tested with Java 5, and the behavior is the same as for Java 7: this doesn't appear to be Java version-specific.

Windows 7+ is the common thread. I'm guessing this is related to [the new ConHost.exe process](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/10/05/windows-7-windows-server-2008-r2-console-host.aspx) added in Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I would think that the standard streams of the JVM are determined by the calling OS, rather than the JVM itself. I expect that there is some critical difference between the two contexts, such as one calling the JVM within a command prompt window rather than directly...